# How to make possible to close product tab by clicking this tab after opening in mobile view?

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

I have a question about Magento 2 product tabs.
In mobile view, when I open some product tab(for example DESCRIPTION) I want to press this tab again and it must close. Currently tab closing only when you opening another tab.

Thank you.

I have tried jquery code in footer.phtml file. In browser code inspector CONSOLE - it'works but it somewhy does not work as a code part.

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $(window).load(function() { 
                if($(window).width() < 900) {
                    
                    $('.product.data.items .data.switch').click(function(e){
                        var parrentName = $(this).parent().attr('aria-controls');
                        if($('.data.item.content#'+parrentName).attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') {
                            $('.data.item.content#'+parrentName).hide();
                            $('.data.item.title#tab-label-'+parrentName).removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Will leave it here if someone will have same requirement.
In the theme need to override details.phtml template which locating here: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml
from

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
```

to

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active", "collapsible":"true"}}'>
```